# angular2: How to use EventEmitter on components created during runtime?

Tags: angular, eventemitter

On my Angular app, i have a parent module populate dinamically with other child modules. My child modules have this template:

```typescript
<input type="radio" class="form-control"
[checked] = "message.default == 1"
[value] = "message.default"
(change)="onSelectionChange(message)"
name="default" >
```

and this is ts:

```typescript
export class MessageComponent implements OnInit {
    message: MessageInterface;
    @Output() onCheckedChange = new EventEmitter<MessageInterface>();

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }  

    onSelectionChange(message: MessageInterface) {
        this.onCheckedChange.emit(message); 
    }
}
```

and this is my parent template

```typescript
<div #placeholder  ></div>
```

and ts

```typescript
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('placeholder', {read: ViewContainerRef}) placeHolder;

    ngOnInit() {
        for(let i=0; i<this.aVariable; i++) {
            let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ChildComponent);
            this.placeHolder.createComponent(factory);
        }
    }

    onCheckedChange(message: MessageInterface) {
      console.log("parent intercept");
    }
```

where "aVariable" variable is a value returned from a service that i invoke.

when i click on a radiobutton, no log message is showed, it seems that parent don't receive EventEmitter emit.
What's wrong?

Comment: please paste your selector in the parent view

Comment: you should have something like,
`<child (onCheckedChange)="onCheckedChange($event)"></child>`

Comment: childs are not hardcoded into parent, they're added at runtime with 

  let factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ChildComponent);
        this.placeHolder.createComponent(factory);

where placeHoder is   @ViewChild('placeholder', {read: ViewContainerRef}) placeHolder;

Comment: but, how will you receive the o/p from the child to parent?

Comment: Show complete code for runtime-generation of your childs.

Comment: edited with missing code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You still need to subscribe to those events, even if you create that component(s) during runtime!

```js
let comp = this.placeHolder.createComponent(factory) as ComponentRef<ChildComponent>;
// just to be sure, check some things.. :)
if (!comp || !comp.instance || !comp.instance.onCheckedChange) continue;
comp.instance.onCheckedChange.subscribe(msg => this.onCheckedChange(msg));
```

Comment: I think it should be `comp.instance.onCheckedCahange...`

Comment: Right, even the cast wasn't correct. Thanks for pointing.. :)